# How do I get the boss to attack again 10 seconds after the last attack?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm new in unity and all the programing language so I don't know How do I get the bossPattern to starts again after 10 seconds when the boss pattern is over.  could you can give how to make that?

I want to make sure that the pattern starts again after 10 seconds when the boss pattern is over.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Well have some timer that starts after the last attack?

Comment: Maybe the [`Invoke`][1] method is what you're looking for?
You can specify the time in seconds until a method is executed:

    Invoke("StartBossPattern", 10.0f);

Where "**StartBossPattern**" is the name of your method.


  [1]: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a simple timer and after 10 seconds start your "StartBossPattern" and reset your timer:

```
float timer = 0f;

void Update()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer <= 0f)
    {
        //Start Boss Pattern

        timer = 10f;
    }
}
```

But this is only one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

method 1:

```
float lastAttackTime=0;
float attackTimeGap=10;

void update()
{
if (Time.time-lastAttackTime>attackTimeGap)
{
//attack
lastAttackTime = Time.time;
}
}
```

method 2:

```
void update()
{
startCoroutine(Attack());
}
IEnumerator Attack()
{
//attack
yeild return new WaitForSeconds(10);
startCoroutine(Attack());
}
```